# Stacking rotated elements vertically in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to stack the popup-text class p element and the close p class element directly on top of each other. I am having trouble aligning them vertically since they are both rotated. I tried display: inline-block but that does not seem to work. I was wondering if anyone has experience aligning rotated elements.

```
    <div class="popup">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://bing.com">    
    <p class="popup-text"> Save 20% | </p>
    <a target="_blank"  href="https://google.com"<p class="close">+</p></a>

     </a>

    </div>

   
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   .popup {
    background-color: #f48277;
    width: 70px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 30vh;
    border-radius: 70px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }

    .close {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    color: #FFFFFF;
   font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 26px;
    }

   .popup-text {
    color: white;
     font-size: 26px;
     font-weight: bold;
     writing-mode: vertical-rl;
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     }
```

Comment: You can't have nested anchor (a) elements. Please correct the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

We've restructured our html a bit, as the location of the closing tag for one of the links didn't make sense and was a bit confusing to work with.  Also, some of the formatting is made to be more consistent.

```
<div class="popup">
  <div>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://bing.com">
      <p class="popup-text"> Save 20% | </p>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank"  href="https://google.com">
      <p class="close">+</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The css now looks like this

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup {
    background-color: #f48277;
    width: 70px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 30vh;
    border-radius: 70px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.popup div {
    display: flex;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.close {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 26px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.popup-text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

An inner div has been added and rotated.  See the .popup div selector.  White-space no-wrap has been added to the .popup-text class, as we don't want the paragraph element trying to conform to the container width since we've rotated its parent.